# How EtherScan keep the complete track of NFT(ERC721 token) transaction

Tags: web3js, etherscan, erc-721, nft

My Usecase is to get transaction hash and show from which to which wallet a NFT was transferred. but when i use getTransaction of web3.js it returns me contract address in **to** field instead of wallet/new owner address

**EDIT**
this is what im doing right now (just for testing purposes)

```
 console.log(await web3.eth.getTransaction("0x93dfc88f391fc68d8fe8e75e6c37dbb8011a3bf872433909766341953464ee43"))
```

[image]
this is getTransaction responce

[image]
this is info given by ether scan

now as you can see in GetTransaction response we get contract address but what i want the to from tokens transferred

Comment: Please show us code and what you tried

Comment: You have to use the logs from the transaction's receipt. Every ERC-721 transfer generates a log entry with sender, recipient and amount.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Edited

Comment: @Ismael sure i'll look into this , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One transaction can have an arbitrary number of ERC-721 transactions. Each transaction will emit a `Transfer` event.

The typical way to do it is:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {from: account});
contract.events.Transfer(
  {filter: {from: account}}, fromBlock: 0},
  function(error, event){ console.log(event); }
)
```

This can be filtered per block, TX, accounts, etc.